# iOS, how to backup file (coredata and plist) to iCloud, and retrieve?

Tags: ios, backup, plist, icloud

I have an App that has almost completed, except iCloud support. Now my user's data consists of **coredata (called sqlite?)** and **some plist files**. User's activity change these files all the time. I want my App could backup these files to the user's iCloud account. How could I do it?

I always refer to Apple official documents, I'm reading [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011317) but still in vague.

I'm wondering whether it is a quick example?

Thanks

////////////////////////Edited//////////////////////////
One day left but no answer or comment at all. Didn't I make my self clear?
Well, I just want my iCould restore all user's data and backup if needed. I don't need them to be auto-sync but trigered by user's action.

Please help.